# Unable to load file or assembly 'System.web.Extensions' version=1.0.61025 While migrating VS 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I had web application developed in VS 2005 + Sql server 2005 + Ajax 1.0 Extension .
(Developed in Windows Server 2005)
Now i am migrating to VS 2008.(Windows Server 2008 + Sql server 2008)

After opening and compile my Existing application in VS 2008,i am getting error.

Errors :-

1. `Unable to load file or assembly 'System.web.Extenstions'' version=1.0.61025.`
   (I think it because of AJAX Extension version.So i installed AJAX Extension 1.0 but it will give me ambiguous error so i uninstalled.I am added reference for version=3.5.0 but again unsuccessful.)
   What i will do now?
2. Also i used 'Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum', Version=9.0.242.0 in VS 2005.
   (Are i have to change it to version=10.0.0.0? by adding reference to new version.)
3. I also used crystal report.(Is there is anything to do with it?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have done it.

Solution:- while opening the same project in VS 2008, it will ask you for framwork type to choose.
If you choose and Upgrade .Net 3.5 it will give you error.
In that case you have to remove old reference and add new refrences dll.

like In place SqlServer version=9.0 you have to add version=10.0 dll.

Thanks